# Configuration between MongoDB,Cordova and Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cordova, hybrid

How to integrate mongodb, nodejs and cordova in eclipse. As i am building hybrid mobile application.Basically i am looking for configuration between these three.

Answer (score 1):

I am using similar technologies and discovered that MongoDB cannot be integrated directly on Android/Eclipse.

MongoDB is designed to run on a server with more resources than mobile typically offers, eg a lot of RAM with specialized memory mapping etc.  I would not expect Cordova integration in the near future.

If the design is already set on Mongo/Node, you'll have to create your own persistent data layer.  Check out this blog post and sample project (GIT):

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/04/sample-application-with-backbone-js-and-twitter-bootstrap-updated-and-improved/

An earlier post specifically for PhoneGap / Cordova:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/06/building-modular-mobile-phonegap-apps-with-backbone-js-requirejs-and-topcoat/

If you are flexible on technologies, consider using CouchBase:

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/powering-hybrid-mobile-apps-couchbase/

> Basically, it takes care of much of developer plumbing and allows you
>   to focus on building your amazing app. There are three components to
>   it:
>
> Couchbase Lite – A standalone on-device lightweight embedded JSON database; you will use this to stow away data locally on the mobile
>   device with full CRUD (Create | Read | Update | Delete) features.
>
> Sync Gateway – The bridge that allows you to securely synchronize on-device Couchbase Lite data with Couchbase Server backend.
>
> Couchbase Server – A high performance scalable JSON database that serves as your backend in the cloud.

CouchBase is also compatible with NodeJS:

http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/introduction.html

> The Couchbase Node.js SDK allows you to connect to a Couchbase cluster
>   from Node.js. It is a native Node.js modules and uses Couchbase's high
>   performance C library to handle communicating to the cluster over
>   Couchbase’s binary protocols.